# Use Emacs registers in Isearch search string

Tags: search, emacs

I'm trying to use register values within an Isearch: `C-s C-x r i`

`C-x r i a` would normally insert the value of register `a` into the buffer. However this does not work during Isearch.

`C-x` exits Isearch and the register value is inserted into the current buffer.

Is there a special command that I need to prefix the insertion with or is there another way to insert a register into the Isearch search string?

Comment: Note that `isearch` doesn't actually use the minibuffer. When the minibuffer *is* active (e.g. after typing `M-e` to edit the search string), you *can* use the register commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are within isearch, you can hit `M-e` to enter a "normal" editing mode. Then you can edit the search string in the minibuffer, with all the usual commands available, including `C-x r i`.  When you're done, hit `RET` to resume isearch with the new search string.

---

Another way to do this is to use "non-interactive" search, `M-x search-forward`. Then all editing commands are available in the minibuffer by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) then you need only hit **`C-x r g`** (command `isearchp-append-register`) during Isearch, to append the string contents of a register to the current search string.

You are prompted for the register to use.  This is the same key that is bound globally to
`insert-register`.  If you want this key to instead *exit* Isearch
and insert the register in the *buffer*, then define this key in
`isearch-mode-map` as `nil` (i.e., unbind it), and optionally
bind `isearchp-append-register` to a different key in
`isearch-mode-map`.